# Confusing result from post-hoc analysis using mixed linear model

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, contrasts, lsmeans

I am fitting a mixed model:

```
lmer1.model=lmer(share ~ gender+ age_group + overall_photo_share_freq_group+
     affiliative_score_group*valence_group*condition+
     self_enhancing_score_group*valence_group*condition+
     self_defeating_score_group*valence_group*condition+
     aggressive_score_group*valence_group*condition+ 
     (1|pid), data = picshare_df, REML = FALSE)
```

The `affiliative_score_group` has three levels: `High`, `Medium`, and `Low`. From the model summary, I see that the coefficient for `High` level is significant, but not for the `Medium` level (`Low` is the reference level).

```
Fixed effects:

Estimate    Std. Error df        t value Pr(>|t|)    
affiliative_score_groupMedium                                                                    
-5.614e-02  1.152e-01  5.081e+02  -0.487 0.626145    
affiliative_score_groupHigh                                                                   
-2.858e-01  1.351e-01  5.089e+02  -2.116 0.034806 *
```

However, if I conduct post-hoc tests for the same factor, I get significant results for both levels.

```
lsmeans(lmer1.model, list(trt.vs.ctrl1~affiliative_score_group))
$`differences from control of affiliative_score_group`
 contrast     estimate     SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Medium - Low   -0.156 0.0659 Inf -2.373  0.0339 
 High - Low     -0.180 0.0718 Inf -2.505  0.0237
```

**Question**
Why I am getting different results? Which one should I report?

**Update**

I have executed a simpler model as per suggestions in the comments.

```
lmer1.model=lmer(share ~ gender+ age_group + overall_photo_share_freq_group+
     affiliative_score_group*valence_group*condition+
     (1|pid), data = picshare_df, REML = FALSE)
```

Now there is no significant *main effect* of `affiliative_score_group`. Also no significant interaction for post-hoc tests using `lsmeans`.

```
$`differences from control of affiliative_score_group`
 contrast     estimate     SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Medium - Low -0.04836 0.0668 Inf -0.724  0.6831 
 High - Low    0.00142 0.0627 Inf  0.023  0.9990
```

For each of the variables, the reference category is the first one of the levels:
`condition`: `baseline`,`perspective_taking`,`privacy_perspective`

`affiliative_score_group`: `Low`,`Medium`, `High`

`valence_group`: `very_negative`,`negative`,`positive`,`very_positive`

Comment: do you get a warning about "contrasts may be misleading due to involvement in interactions" ... ?

Comment: @BenBolker, I do. Also, I get the same result using `testInteractions` from `phia` package. Is this about correcting for covariates/imbalance in data during fitting the whole model?

Comment: Try removing some of the interactions involving the variables of interest. Especially those with variables not of interest. Once you do that re-run `lsmeans()`. As potentially hinted at by Ben's comment, I think your current model is too complicated as is to be able to compare the coefficient estimates from `lmer` to the `lsmeans` results.

Comment: @ErikRuzek, I did that, and the values are still different although they matches in terms of significance. But I will need to add all the interactions in the final model. Consequently, I am more interested in learning whey they are different and which one to report, rather than making them the same.

Comment: We would need to see the simplified model along with its coefficients and then the lsmeans code and results to be able to diagnose this. The coefficients of interactions in regression can change based on how you coded the variables, most importantly whether and what is the 0 category or value for the interacting variable. lsmeans sidesteps this issue somewhat, which is why they are not always the same.

Comment: @ErikRuzek, I have updated the question.

Comment: Thanks, @Rakib. Can you add the coefficients for `lmer1.model` as well as the `lsmeans` code you used.

Comment: You have three fixed factors here, along with interactions; yet in your post hoc tests you have immediately zoomed down to one factor. You have not said anything about the model summary effects of those other two factors or their interactions. This is like trying to describe an elephant's trunk by looking only at its tail. You need to look at the complete picture before you start averaging over those other two factors.

Comment: Annother issue is that you seem to use the term "interaction" incorrectly, mixing it up with "pairwise differences." I suggest you do something like `emmeans::emmip(lmer1.model, condition ~ affiliative_score_group | valence_group)`. This will show the predicted values for all the factor combinations and how they relate to one another. The marginal EMMs are averages of these, and I think your confusion probably stems from trying to average together sets of means that have entirely different patterns.